# How can I share images , video and text on facebook , twitter and google plus from my webpage?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, twitter

I am working on http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/thelist/ webpage. There are some videos , images and text on this page. I want to share these contect from this page to facebook , twitter and google plus. Right now I am using plugin add to any to share this. But with plugin i am only able to share title of the page and url of the page. I want to share Images and video and text individually. Please Help.

Comment: Try These - `http://www.sharethis.com/`        `http://www.addthis.com/`

Comment: You can always use the given sdk for fb,twt,google+ to share.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge I'm never come across any kind of plugin which will allow you to share specifically the page contents and not the full page itself. Whatever social share plugin present in WordPress free plugin repository, it will only allow you to share the page or post itself, not any element within it.
Beside the only content sharing plugin I've seen is this `jQuery Pin It Button For Images` (Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-pin-it-button-for-images/) which will show you a pin button whenever you hover on any images present on your site.
If you want to share specific contents of your page/post, I will suggest you to copy the link and then use `HootSuite` to one click share to every social media.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If I do not use any plugin then is it possible by any coding to share page content ? I am asking is it fine to spend time in coding to do this work or I let this ?

Comment: Yah! If you wanna code, you can obviously do that. No problem in that. But what I'm saying is there is no radimate plugin available like this outside.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Facebook, twitter, [Sprybirds](http://sprybirds.com) and google+ uses the meta tags to share the content of a webpage. Facebook uses Open Graph. An example of meta tag uses by facebook for image is `<meta property="og:image" content="your-image-path.jpg">` and by twitter `<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="your-image-path.jpg">`. You only can share contents on these sites which are available in meta tags.You can not share all the page. If you are using wordpress for website or blog then you can use available plugins like [all-sociable](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-sociable/) and otherwise you have to create your own plugin.
  If you want to create own buttons to share contents on These sites then you can do these things.

- For Sprybirds

  `<a href="http://sprybirds.com/get-content?url=PUT-PAGE-URL"></a>`
- For Facebook

  `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=PUT-PAGE-URL"></a>`
- For Google Plus

  `<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=PUT-PAGE-URL"></a>`
- For twitter

  `<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=PUT-PAGE-URL"></a>`

> Where "PUT-PAGE-URL" is the url of that page from which you want to share the content on these sites. The content of this page will share on these sites.
>   **Request** If you are planning to put these buttons and my answer is helpfull for you please don't forget to also create our social networking website Sprybirds.com button on you website.

List item